# Checking for Diagonal Dominate Matrix In Julia

Tags: julia

I'm working on a project in Julia where I create a 13x13 matrix with random numbers, then I check if that matrix is diagonally dominate. I'm pretty new with Julia, but I've worked a lot with some other prgrams so this program is kind of an iteration off of python.

```
function checkD()
A=2*rand(13,13).-1
G=A'A
j=1
i=1
for i=1:13
    sum = 0
    for j=1:13
        sum = sum + abs.(G[i,j])
    end
    sum = sum - abs.(G[i,i])
    if(abs.(G[i,i]) < sum)
        return false
    end
    return true
end
```

I understand the declaration of the j and i at the start is a little redundant but for now I leave them there. My issue is that I keep getting false even though I know that the matrix G=A'A is diagonally dominate.

Comment: It might be worth it to go through your logic step by step in the REPL to check what your function is actually doing. For example, you have a loop over a variable `j` that is not being used, and you have a loop over `i` that is exiting after the first iteration. I don't think that is what you intend to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your definition is the following:

> a diagonally dominant matrix is a square matrix such that in each row, the absolute value of the term on the diagonal is greater than or equal to the sum of absolute values of the rest of the terms in that row

You can use this code to check whether matrix `a` is diagonally dominant (requires `using LinearAlgebra`):

```
all(sum(abs.(a),dims=2) .<= 2abs.(diag(a)))
```

Comment: Here's a version that doesn't allocate and bails out early: `all(sum(view(G, i, :)) <= 2abs(G[i, i]) for i in axes(G, 1))`

Comment: @DNF  +1. I was aiming at the smallest number of characters possible :-)

Comment: Ah. Then, may I suggest: `all(sum(abs,G;dims=2) .<= 2abs.(diag(G)))` ;)

Comment: great! you won :-)